# How to retrieve backed-up game data from iCloud after reinstalling a game?

Tags: applications, icloud

I deleted a game from my iPad and was wondering if i could retrieve the data somehow, because the game was backed up on iCloud and when i reinstalled it all my data was gone. How do i retrieve the data specifically for this app from iCloud.

Comment: Where to you backup your iPad to, your computer (via iTunes) or iCloud?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Apple Support topic](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4859) on the subject, your only option is to restore your entire phone from a recent backup.

The article does not *explicitly* report that there is not a way to selectively restore data, but it *does* explicitly state the way in which data is restored to a phone--all at once from a backup.

Comment: This is stupid, terrible, and correct :(